# Linux from Scratch 8.1. Issue related to Zlib 1.2.11

Tags: linux, make, lfs

I am doing Linux from Scratch. I am currently at 6.11 section i.e zlib 1.2.11 in LFS 8.2 . I did the following as per the book:

1) Prepare Zlib for compilation:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

2)Compile the package:

```
make
```

3) To test the results, issue:

```
make check
```

I get the following output:

```
 (lfs chroot) root:/sources/zlib-1.2.11# make check
/bin/sh: line 1: ./minigzip: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./minigzip: No such file or directory
        *** zlib test FAILED ***
/bin/sh: line 5: ./minigzipsh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 5: ./minigzipsh: No such file or directory
        *** zlib shared test FAILED ***
/bin/sh: line 1: ./minigzip64: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./minigzip64: No such file or directory
        *** zlib 64-bit test FAILED ***
(lfs chroot) root:/sources/zlib-1.2.11#
```

Can anyone help me with this with respect to LFS? Thank you in Advance.

Other Ouput:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
Checking for gcc...
Checking for shared library support...
Building shared library libz.so.1.2.11 with gcc.
Checking for size_t... Yes.
Checking for off64_t... Yes.
Checking for fseeko... Yes.
Checking for strerror... Yes.
Checking for unistd.h... Yes.
Checking for stdarg.h... Yes.
Checking whether to use vs[n]printf() or s[n]printf()... using vs[n]printf().
Checking for vsnprintf() in stdio.h... Yes.
Checking for return value of vsnprintf()... Yes.
Checking for attribute(visibility) support... Yes.
root:/sources/zlib-1.2.11# make
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -I. -c -o example.o test/example.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o adler32.o adler32.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o crc32.o crc32.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o deflate.o deflate.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o infback.o infback.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o inffast.o inffast.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o inflate.o inflate.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o inftrees.o inftrees.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o trees.o trees.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o zutil.o zutil.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o compress.o compress.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o uncompr.o uncompr.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o gzclose.o gzclose.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o gzlib.o gzlib.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o gzread.o gzread.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -c -o gzwrite.o gzwrite.c
ar rc libz.a adler32.o crc32.o deflate.o infback.o inffast.o inflate.o inftrees.o trees.o zutil.o compress.o uncompr.o gzclose.o gzlib.o gzread.o gzwrite.o 
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -o example example.o -L. libz.a
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -I. -c -o minigzip.o test/minigzip.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -o minigzip minigzip.o -L. libz.a
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/adler32.o adler32.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/crc32.o crc32.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/deflate.o deflate.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/infback.o infback.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/inffast.o inffast.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/inflate.o inflate.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/inftrees.o inftrees.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/trees.o trees.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/zutil.o zutil.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/compress.o compress.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/uncompr.o uncompr.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/gzclose.o gzclose.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/gzlib.o gzlib.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/gzread.o gzread.c
gcc -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN  -DPIC -c -o objs/gzwrite.o gzwrite.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libz.so.1,--version-script,zlib.map -O3 -fPIC -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -o libz.so.1.2.11 adler32.lo crc32.lo deflate.lo infback.lo inffast.lo inflate.lo inftrees.lo trees.lo zutil.lo compress.lo uncompr.lo gzclose.lo gzlib.lo gzread.lo gzwrite.lo  -lc 
rm -f libz.so libz.so.1
ln -s libz.so.1.2.11 libz.so
ln -s libz.so.1.2.11 libz.so.1
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -o examplesh example.o -L. libz.so.1.2.11
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -o minigzipsh minigzip.o -L. libz.so.1.2.11
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c -o example64.o test/example.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -o example64 example64.o -L. libz.a
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c -o minigzip64.o test/minigzip.c
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -o minigzip64 minigzip64.o -L. libz.a
root:/sources/zlib-1.2.11# make check
/bin/sh: line 1: ./minigzip: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./minigzip: No such file or directory
        *** zlib test FAILED ***
/bin/sh: line 5: ./minigzipsh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 5: ./minigzipsh: No such file or directory
        *** zlib shared test FAILED ***
/bin/sh: line 1: ./minigzip64: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./minigzip64: No such file or directory
        *** zlib 64-bit test FAILED ***
root:/sources/zlib-1.2.11#
```

Comment: Did step 2 complete successfully? What were the last few lines of output from `make`?

Comment: no minigzip in directory @dsstorefile

Comment: The executable´s `zlib-1.2.11/{ minigzip, minigzip64, minigzipsh }` are present after `make`, unless 'make' fails.

Comment: Make did not give any error.I found the files in directory.But why isnt existing? What could be the issue for the failure.

Comment: I can see the word `chroot` in you message. When do you enter the chroot and does it contain `ld.so` and other needed binaries and libraries?

Comment: i followed the book exactly @Kusalananda. i don`t get the error here.

Comment: @PRANAYKASTHALA You don't get the error? So your issue is resolved then?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this on my OpenBSD machine, and the `make` output clearly states that the `minigzip` binary was built:

```
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -o minigzip minigzip.o -L. libz.a
```

The same is true for the other executables that `make` creates.

These executable files should be available in the current directory after having run `make`.

The only reason I can think of that would prevent the files from executing correctly is that the current partition is mounted with the `noexec` mount option, or that the chroot you are in when you run `make check` (as evident from you prompt at one point) is somehow not set up properly.

Comment: I did not get the last paragraph. What do you mean by it.

Comment: @PRANAYKASTHALA I meant that if the executables are present but not able to run, then one reason for that may be that the partition is mounted with a mount option that prevents executables from running.